# Actualizar ArrayList usando Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Llevo intentando unas horas sacar el objeto "lista" pero no lo consigo. El problema viene que por lo que he leído mi variable "lista" sale vacío por el return ya que las operaciones con Firebase tardan un tiempo y no se espera a acabar. La variable lista se actualiza correctamente, el único problema que tengo es que no consigo sacarla de allí y tampoco consigo ver como se podría adaptar mi código a una solución posible (desconozco mucho el entorno Android y más el lenguaje Kotlin).

```
 private fun historialUsuario(): ArrayList<Oferta> {
        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
            val id: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
            var i: Int = 0
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            val lista: ArrayList<Oferta> = ArrayList()
            val ofertas = db.collection("canjeadas").whereEqualTo("idUsuario", user!!.uid)
            ofertas.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
                for (document in documentSnapshot) {
                    //println(document.id)
                    id.addAll(listOf(document.id))
                    //val id = document.id
                    val idOferta = document.get("idOferta").toString()
                    val titulo = db.collection("ofertes").document(idOferta).get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
                        //descr.addAll(listOf(documentSnapshot.get("descripcio").toString()))
                        val descr = documentSnapshot.get("descripcio").toString()


                        lista.add(Oferta(id[i], descr, descr))
                        i++
                    }
//PROBLEMA Q DEVUELVE VACIO EL ARRAY, SOLUCIONAR
                }
            }

            println("INDICES LISTA")
            println(lista.indices)
            return lista

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removiendo los callbacks quedaría mas o menos así

```
private suspend fun historialUsuario(): List<Oferta> {
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        return db.collection("canjeadas").whereEqualTo("idUsuario", user!!.uid).get()
            .await().documents.map { document ->
                val idOferta = document.getString("idOferta")!!
                val oferta = db.collection("ofertas").document(idOferta).get().await()
                Oferta(
                    document.id,
                    oferta.getString("titulo")!!,
                    oferta.getString("descripcion")!!
                )
            }
    }
```

pero hay varias consideraciones que deberías tener en cuenta:

- en lugar de usar strings directamente en tu código, lo cual es muy propenso a errores, deberias usar constantes u obtener los nombres de las propiedades por reflejo
- firestore no es una base de datos relacional por lo que deberías evitar hacer consultas tipo JOIN siempre que sea posible. Por ejemplo en este caso los documtos de la colección "canjeadas" podrían tener un campo "tituloOferta".
- para una mejor abstracción, tu clase "Oferta" debería tener un método para crear una instancia a partir de un DocumentSnapshop

Ejemplo:

```
class Oferta(val id: String, val titulo: String, val descripcion: String) {
        companion object {
            fun DocumentSnapshot.toOferta(): Oferta = Oferta(
                // ejemplo de reflection
                getString(Oferta::titulo.name)!!,
                getString(Oferta::descripcion.name)!!,
                ...
            )
        }
    }
```

Aplicando esto, la legibilidad de tu funcción mejora considerablemente

```
private suspend fun historialUsuario() = db.collection("canjeadas")
    .whereEqualTo("idUsuario", Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid)
    .get().await().documents.map { it.toOferta() }
```